# Identify barrel connector from Chevrolet Silverado 6V Powered Ride on Toy

Tags: identification, connector

[image: Connector]

I believe the label has the following printed on it:

```
GVXW
ZGCY
0.5A 240VDC
```

I am unable to locate anything via google.

### Assumption

It is a fused female barrel connector for charging the power wheel.  My multi-meter shows that the Voltage no longer passes through it (fuse broken).

Any assistance would be appreciated, mostly looking for a drop-in replacement to get my kid's power wheel back in working order.

Comment: how did you determine that there is no connection? ... where did you measure the voltages?

Comment: @jsotola, on the back, there are three pins, 1 has two red wires on it, and the other two have black cables connected to them.  There is 6V coming in and 0V coming out, the same when measuring further down the wire in the main terminal.  If you wiggle the closest black wire, you can get it to make contact, and the headlights will turn on.

Comment: that sounds like a bad internal switch

Comment: @jsotola, any chance of repairing that? or if I need to replace know where?

Answer (score 0):

I found this [replacement part](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08Q7VJ5H2), although I'm not sure what the part is exactly.

Search phrase: `Power Storage Power Charging Interface 3-Pins Port`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).